# Android Kotlin scan QR code and send user to application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, qr-code

I have a QR code generator inside my application. Now if I am trying to scan this QR code just with phone camera it shows all information of QR code, but I want to get a message like ***"Read this QR code through AppName"*** and when I click it my application opens and this QR code give me information inside my application.

Is it possible to do? What should I set in QR code generator to do this thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my app few months back. What I did was, instead of generating QR code for actual data, I generated the QR code for a unique ID (a id to uniquely identify content) with the message "Read this QR Code with YourAppName to get the content".

Reading the QR code from your APP will give you the unique ID, use that Id to load the content either from local storage or from API like "https://yourserver/api/posts?postId=" and display it to the user.

Comment: But is it possible to make systemically, without making a unique ID?